# Seeking word equations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

is there a general word equation so I can learn how to write out the following:

[image]

With chlorine, it seems to be: Hydrocarbon + Chlorine ---> ____ + HCL

With Hexane, it seems to be: Hydrocarbon + Br ---> ____ + HBr

I am not sure how to derive the first part of the final reaction (____)

It seems that methane has lost one hydrogen atom.

It seems that hexane has lost one hydrogen atom too.

Does that mean, if it was say Pentane with Chlorine, the first part of the final reaction would be CH4CL (not ch5cl) ? Likewise, would Pentane with Bromine be C6H12BR (and not c6h13br)

It feels like i'm rote-learning a skill, wonder where my knowledge is missing hmm..

Comment: In each case an atom of a halogen has replaced one of the hydrogens on the alkane.  That hydrogen sticks to the other halogen atom, forming an acid.  Your missing product is a called a haloalkane or an alkyl halide.  Pentane, C5H12, would turn into bromopentane, C5H11Br.  If this is for an organic chemistry class, your professor should have talked about the mechanism of the reaction, and not just its existence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question completely, but If you want to understand what's happening in an organic reaction you need to know which type of reaction is in question and you have to look at the mechanism. This is a [radical reaction](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/freerad/ch4andcl2.html) with the following mechanism (excluding the termination step):

[image]